# pthread_create followed by pthread_detach still results in possibly lost error in Valgrind

Tags: c, multithreading, memory, memory-leaks, pthreads

I'm having a problem with Valgrind telling me I have some memory possible lost:

```
==23205== 544 bytes in 2 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 156 of 265
==23205==    at 0x6022879: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23205==    by 0x540E209: allocate_dtv (in /lib/ld-2.12.1.so)
==23205==    by 0x540E91D: _dl_allocate_tls (in /lib/ld-2.12.1.so)
==23205==    by 0x623068D: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /lib/libpthread-2.12.1.so)
==23205==    by 0x758D66: MTPCreateThreadPool (MTP.c:290)
==23205==    by 0x405787: main (MServer.c:317)
```

The code that creates these threads (MTPCreateThreadPool) basically gets an index into a block of waiting pthread_t slots, and creates a thread with that. TI becomes a pointer to a struct that has a thread index and a pthread_t. (simplified/sanitized):

```
for (tindex = 0; tindex < NumThreads; tindex++)
  {
  int rc;
  TI = &TP->ThreadInfo[tindex];
  TI->ThreadID = tindex;

  rc = pthread_create(&TI->ThreadHandle,NULL,MTPHandleRequestsLoop,TI);
  /* check for non-success that I've omitted */
  pthread_detach(&TI->ThreadHandle);
  }
```

Then we have a function MTPDestroyThreadPool that loops through all the threads we created and cancels them (since the MTPHandleRequestsLoop doesn't exit).

```
for (tindex = 0; tindex < NumThreads; tindex++)
  {
  pthread_cancel(TP->ThreadInfo[tindex].ThreadHandle);
  }
```

I've read elsewhere (including other questions here on SO) that detaching a thread explicitly would prevent this possibly lost error, but it clearly isn't.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One reason could be that pthread_cancel doesn't actually cancel the thread - it's not guaranteed to. Thread cancellation is asynchronous; pthread_cancel returns immediately, but cancellation may be deferred until the next cancellation point. In that case, the threads may still be around when Valgrind collects statistics.

Comment: It was also what I was about to suggest, and possibly test the return value of `pthread_cancel`

Comment: So if any of the threads (potentially all) are blocking on a semaphore, the cancel will return immediately, but since they're blocked it's entirely likely that the main server process will exit before they actually cancel?

Comment: sem_wait is a cancellation point (http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?cancellation+5), so if the thread is cancellable, the wait should get cancelled right away. A thread spinning in an infinite loop is a better candidate. However, you should first establish whether that's what happening, i.e. if the threads do get cancelled or not.

Comment: I've checked the return value of pthread_cancel() (it's 0), and the application shuts down without any trouble from the threads that are waiting for the semaphore. So if sem_wait is a cancellation point, is there any way to determine that the thread actually cancels, say by placing a print statement at the end of the thread's function? Or would the cancellation stop the execution at the call to sem_wait?

Answer (score 8):

glibc's threads implementation intentionally leaks memory. It keeps the memory allocated to a thread context cached to reuse the next time a thread is created. I did some benchmarking versus an implementation without the caching, and it seems the caching shaves 50% off the otherwise-optimal time for `pthread_create`, but drastically slows down `pthread_join`, for a net loss. Of course it's still a (small) gain if what you care about is thread creation latency and not throughput.

Also note that it's very difficult for a detached thread to deallocate its context, even if it wanted to. With a joinable thread, the thread that calls `pthread_join` can deallocate the context, but a detached thread would have to be able to operate with no stack during the interval between deallocating its context and terminating itself. This can only be achieved by writing that small piece of code in pure asm.

Wondering how detached threads' contexts get returned to the cache without a similar race condition? Linux has a feature to zero-out an `int` at a particular address (registered by the userspace threads library) when the thread terminates. So the thread can add its own context to the cache safely, since until it terminates, other threads will still see a nonzero value (usually its thread-id) at this address and interpret that to mean that the context is still in use.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a thread joinable to detach it immediately makes not much sense to me. This creates nothing but overhead for the system.

I'd start the threads detached from the start, you have your shared `ThreadInfo` data structure anyhow to control your threads.

Also I'd have a flag or something like that in your per thread argument  `ThreadInfo` that tells the thread to shutdown in a controlled way.

Comment: Good point. I didn't write the code in question, I'm just looking for the cause (and cure) of the "possibly lost" message in Valgrind, but I may fix that too while I'm at it.